# Rotational Energy in Pendulum and kenatictic energy from the point view of origin

Tags: classical-mechanics

For a point mass with constrain $l>0$ from the origin. (and no gravitational force just yet.)

The energy of the system can be analyzed in two ways:

1. From the point view of the origin. The system has rotational energy $E_{sr}$.
2. From the point view of the object. The object does not have rotational energy $E_{br}=0$, and $E_{bk}=E_{sr}$(The kinetic energy of the object from point view of body equal to the calculated rotation energy from point of the system.) from the mathematics.

However, I still have one piece that was not resolved. In order for the analysis to be consistent, $E_{st}$(total energy of the system) must be equal to $E_{bt}$(total energy form the point view of the body).

1. This would mean $E_{sk}=0$, but although the system does not move in time average, it's central of mass does move! So how can $E_{sk}=0$? Is there any mistakes?
2. What if we introduce a gravity force?(a classical simple pendulum) Will the analysis be any different?

Comment: What are you trying to find?

Comment: @jmh Why kinetic energy from the view of the system is $E_{sk}=0$, but it's center of mass is actually moving.(Notice the total energy is only $\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ or you can write it in rotational form; so if the system has rotational energy, the kinetic part must be $0$.)